# GLSL version 3.30 not supported with Mesa 19.2.8

Tags: graphics-card, opengl

I want to do some OpenGL coding with C# (using OpenTK). And whenever I try running the code I get:

`0:1(10): error: GLSL 3.30 is not supported. Supported versions are: 1.10, 1.20, 1.30, 1.00 ES, 3.00 ES, 3.10 ES, and 3.20 ES`

Which is strange since I have Mesa 19.2.8 installed. When I run `inxi -Gx` I get:

```
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 620 vendor: Acer Incorporated ALI 
  driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
  resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2) 
  v: 4.5 Mesa 19.2.8 direct render: Yes
```

I should be able to support version 3.30, but I somehow can't. I also know for a fact that it isn't because of my code as it works perfectly fine on Windows. I've been looking at this for about a week and I would really like some help.

Thanks in advance.

P.S. Upon request here's the `glxinfo | grep 'version'` info:

```
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.3
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.2
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.2.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

Comment: What is the output of `glxinfo`?

Comment: The output is too long to put in a comment or in the main text, what part are you interested in @Mokubai ?

Comment: Forgot how long it can be... edit the output of `glxinfo | grep version` into your post please. Pretty sure one of the lines should be your supported GLSL version.

Comment: Hmmm. I remember from past experience that the Intel Linux drivers can be somewhat quirky and lag quite heavily behind their Windows counterparts. Is your program intentionally calling for OpenGL ES rather than "normal" OpenGL?

Comment: No it's directly calling normal OpenGL as in: #version 330